# Multiple apps in umbraco with IApplicationEventHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, umbraco6

I recently started refactoring my site resulting in the following situation. I have a separate project containing all the surface controllers, views etc for the frontend users. In this project there is also StartupEventHandler wich registers the interfaces, controllers etc using AutoFac. I started a second project file containing the controllers, etc for the backend users. This project also uses AutoFac in the startupeventhandler and registers practically the same iterfaces as both front end en backend share the same services amongst them.

Now when I start the site, the frontend looks good. But when going via the umbraco backend the views dont get rendered with an error "Parameterless constructors not found". When I rebuild and restart, the backend page gets rendered without errors, but now the frontend pages give me the same error. Until I restart the site.

My guess I has to do with AutoFac and two startup handlers. The handlers each reside in their own assembly and namespace ...web.client and ...web.admin.

Anyone any clue on how to resolve this. I dont think it has to do with Umbraco as there are plenty of plugins which probably have also their own startup handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a proper solution. As I told in my question I had a separate project productname.customername.web.client and productname.customername.web.admin. What I have done is taking all the start up event logic out of those projects, created a new project productname.customername.web and put in there. From there I added a reference to both client and admin project and registered the controllers. It works fine now.